# Show Configurable Products in Magento Low Stock Report

Tags: configurable-product, reports

Is it possible for Configurable Products to be shown in Magento Reports? More specifically the Low Stock Report. I tried attributing an individual quantity to a Configurable Product but it still didn't show up in the Report.

My configurable products have the Manage Stock field set to 'No'.